# Should I create a Factless Fact Table or Denormalise my table

Tags: database-design, dimensional-modeling

I am creating a data warehouse from a store database and I have a question regarding the design of my dimensions and facts.

In the store database a table exists for Person, Person_Address and Person_Address_Type. These are linked by another tabled name Entity_Address_ID which links the three tables by their primary keys to give details on what a person's address is and what type of address it is.

My question is, should I create a dimension for all three tables, and a fact-less fact table to link them together or should I de-normalise my dimensions and add to each dimension a foreign key for the address  and address type they are linked too?

Here is a very quick UML of what the current database looks like to provide clarification
[image: UML of Problem]

Comment: Based on your access pattern, you should decide.I believe : you can denormalise it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge them.  Sometimes it's worthwhile to have a separate `Addresses` table, but generally it's simplest to make those fields of a single `Customers` dimension.  Because addresses are nearly unique, you're not going to save many records by hiving them out to their own table.

If your `Customers` table is really large, and addresses change relatively often then moving `Addresses` out as a Type-4 SCD could be a worthwhile optimization, but a small one.

If there's interest in analyzing customers independently of their specific sales (e.g., "20% of our top-100 customers are international"), you can absolutely add a `NumCustomers` dummy column to this `Customers` table to turn it into a factless fact table.